# Android Paging 3 doesnt show Loadstate Adapter

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-library, android-paging-3

I have followed a tutorial to add Loadstate Adapter to the Recyclerview Adapter on Android Paging 3 but currently, it's not showing. This is how I am updating the Adapter.

```
 lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.searchProducts(searchParam, channelId, categoryId)
                .collectLatest {
                    binding.allProductRecyclerView.isVisible = true
                    adapter.submitData(it)
                }
```

This is how I am adding the LoadState Adapter

```
  binding.allProductRecyclerView.adapter = adapter.withLoadStateFooter(
        footer = ProductLoadingStateAdapter()
    )
```

[This is the gist of LoadStateAdapter](https://gist.github.com/ronnieotieno/8267d57e55e377e670f4d0125eb59540) also[Activity Layout](https://gist.github.com/ronnieotieno/6d7aad065804c7cad749adc8db27ba9f) and [load state Item](https://gist.github.com/ronnieotieno/7f2000e52b1bdac6b3f3e84bfd5ad9ab)

The adapter is working fine, I am also able to get the load states by adding LoadStateListener. It's only the Load State Adapter that isn't working. I have followed and cloned [this](https://github.com/2307vivek/Paging-3-Sample) and it's working perfectly. What might be the issue with mine?

Comment: Have you found any solutions for this?

Comment: Have you found a work around for this, I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the following method in your ProductLoadingStateAdapter like this:

```
class ProductLoadingStateAdapter: LoadStateAdapter<XXX>() {
   override fun onBindViewholder...

   override fun onCreateViewHolder...
  
   override fun displayLoadStateAsItem(loadState: LoadState): Boolean {
      return loadState is LoadState.Loading || loadState is LoadState.Error || LoadState.NotLoading
   }
}
```

If you look into the source code of LoadStateAdapter, it only emits Loading and Error load states to the adapter by default, which means the adapter won't know if the loading process has finished.

So in your case, the following code will always results `progress.visibility` to be `VISIBLE`. Because you can only get `LoadState.Loading` state in your `onBindViewHolder`.

```
//loadState is always LoadState.Loading
if (loadState is LoadState.Loading) progress.visibility =
            View.VISIBLE; txtErrorMessage.visibility = View.GONE
```

Comment: ```loadState is LoadState.Loading``` is not correct. ```loadState.mediator?.refresh is LoadState.Loading``` would be correct.

Comment: my footer for end of list was not showing, overriding displayLoadStateAsItem and always returning true saved the day